# Vue app not appearing after deploying on server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've executed "npm run build"
zip the "dist" folder & uploaded to a hosting
zipped the folder & visited the homepage
but app is not appearing on homepage instead default hosting page appears.

Comment: There's no way anyone can solve this. You would need to extract the contents of your zip file into the document root of your host. Check your host's document root and see if the zip file contents are in there. You should expect to see the `index.html` file and some folders containing your JS, CSS and image files

Comment: i can my files there , still same issue , may be changes free hosting site takes time to update.

Comment: before doing that perhaps run `http-server` or web server for Chrome whether it'll be working fine for the hosting. HTTPS or free-hosting usually take abit (can up to an hour), try hard reload to remove the caches.

Comment: True that......